# Could not find a part of the path nuget\packages\xamarin.firebase.ios.core\8.10.0.1\lib\net6.0-ios15.4

Tags: xamarin, nuget

I want to download MTAdmob plugin from NuGet for visual studio 2022  but at the end of downloading giving this error, please someone help me how to fix it.

Could not find a part of the path

'C:\Users\PC.nuget\packages\xamarin.firebase.ios.core\8.10.0.1\lib\net6.0-ios15.4\Firebase.Core.resources\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.xcframework\ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.framework\Headers\GoogleUtilitiesComponents-umbrella.h'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you upgrade your xamarin project to the .net6.0 or migrate it to the maui? If so, you can download the package named `Plugin.MauiMTAdmob`.

If you project is just a xamarin.Forms, you can download the nuget package named `MarcTron.Admob` which is supported for the xamarin.

Comment: thanks so much Liyun Zhang, I solved it by adding NuGet package path to the environment variable, I appreciate your helping